# Find out size of array in C with Macro

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have trouble understanding if this macro does what it should. It is in a third party dll I am wrapping.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define NULL    0
#else
#define NULL    ((void *)0)
#endif
#define GTO_ARG_SIZE(arg) (long)((arg)==NULL ? 0 : (long)(arg)[0])
```

It is supposed to give the length of arg where arg is in my case a long*. It just points to a long but the Macro is also used when arg is an array of longs...

From my understanding it returns the value at arg[0] if the pointer isn't NULL. But for when arg points to a long, it returns the value of the long, not the size of arg (1)...

RESOLVED:

Like many of you said, the mythical structure contains it's size as the first element. Sorry I have no documentation on the dll so I figured out only after digging a bit into the code. I was wondering at first if I really knew so little about C/C++.
Thanks all

Comment: This is a pretty bad macro; defining its own definition of `NULL` is bound to lead to problems.

Comment: Does the first element in the array contain the size?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Maybe the third-party DLL assumes that arrays are represented like that, with the first element containing the length? That would make kind of sense, if the arrays are also 1-based and bounds-checked.

Hard to be more specific when you're not giving more details about the code.

A more classical macro to compute the length of an array is:

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE(x) ((sizeof x) / (sizeof *x))
```

Do note that this only works for actual arrays, where the array declaration is in scope. This, in particular, does *not* work in C:

```
size_t array_length(const int *data)
{
  /* Note: this is a negative example: IT DOES NOT WORK. */
  return ARRAY_SIZE(data);
}

int main(void)
{
  int test[4711];

  printf("the test[] array is %zu elements long\n", array_length(test));
  return 0;
}
```

The above **will not** print `4711`; the array's size is not part of the `const int *` type that the array *decays* to in the function call. It's not in general possible to do this in C, i.e. find the size of an array that has been passed to a function accepting a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

This simply returns the long pointed to by arg, or zero if the pointer is null.

The only way I can see this returning the length of arg, is if arg is a pointer to a struct (or a long member of a struct) which happens to represent the length of the structure it's used in, seems like a long shot though.

Edit — this mythical structure is more likely to be an array with bounds information as unwind says than anything else.